# Плохо работает программа по поиску слов в файле

Tags: c++, строки, циклы

Есть программа которая должна искать в файле служебные слова с++(которые в массиве words) но находит не все слова(из тех которые может найти) например если закинуть код самой программы то не находит int и while.Почему так происходит?

```
void main()
{
    const string words[35]
    {
        "bool", "break", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const",
        "string", "continue", "default", "delete", "do", "double", "dynamic_cast",
        "else", "enum", "false", "float", "for", "friend", "goto", "if",
        "void", "int",  "long", "namespace", "new", "operator", "private",
        "protected", "public", "return", "short", "unsigned", "sizeof"
    };
    string fName;
    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    cin >> fName;
    ifstream f(fName, ios::in);

    if (!f)
    {
        cout << "Not Found File\n\n";
        return;
    }

    set<string> s;
    string word;

    while (!f.eof())
    {
        f >> word;

        for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
            if (word == words[i])
            {
                s.insert(word);
                break;
            }
    }

    if (s.empty())
        cout << "No C++ words\n\n\n";
    else
    {
        cout << "\nFounded:\n\n";

        for (auto i : s)
            cout << i << endl;

        cout << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум `while` вообще отсутствует в вашем words

Comment: Как максимум вы никак не очищаете слова от точек, скобок и других знаков препинания

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, допустим, с `while` - трудно найти то, чего не ищешь. `int` вполне находит.

Понятно, что в наличии вечная ошибка `while (!f.eof())`, но в данном случае она ни при чем :) Код нормально работает (*), только и того, что я бы рекомендовал основной цикл переписать как

```
while (f >> word)
{
    for (const auto& w : words)
        if (word == w)
        {
            s.insert(word);
            break;
        }
}
```

или даже

```
while (f >> word)
    if (find(begin(words),end(words),word) != end(words))
        s.insert(word);
```

и не использовать никаких магических констант a la 35 - ну вот добавите вы в список слов злополучное `while`, а число в другом месте поменять забудете?...

Ну и мелким шрифтом :)
(*) понятно, что если под словом вы понимаете то же, что и оператор `>>` - стоит только убрать пробелы, скажем, после `if` и писать `if(` слитно, как больше `if` найдены не будут...

Ах, да! `int main`, а не `void`...